# Can I virtualize my ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, virtualbox, cinnamon, mint

I want to switch from Ubuntu to Mint.

Can I somehow turn my laptop's Ubuntu install into a virtual machine that I can then run on my computer so that I can refer to all my applications and settings and such there for when I want to configure my new mint install?

Comment: also would it boot easily in the VM? or is it like Windows where sometimes you can't boot after changing too much hardware?

Comment: A note to duplicate-flaggers; the linked question has a very scary looking accepted answer involving `dd` that may be intimidating to the inexperienced user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are a number of methods for this (search "p2v" for some ideas), here is the way I use:

**What you'll need**

1. External Hard Disk
2. [Bootable Clonezilla
   CD](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php#make)
3. Enough disk space to contain the entire old OS (something like `df -h | grep '^/dev/'` should give you a general idea of how much space this is)

**Steps**

1. Boot from the Clonezilla CD
2. Save the current disk [Here's a good walkthrough](https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image)
3. Install the new OS on your computer
4. Install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)
5. Download a [Clonezilla ISO](https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php)
6. Create a new VM in VirtualBox with a similar configuration to your physical computer
7. Attach the Clonezilla ISO to the VM and boot from it.
8. [Restore the image](https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/02_Restore_disk_image) you took earlier to the VM